# Spring boot - Proguard - ant jar packing: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proguard, obfuscation

We are performing obfuscation on spring boot application:
We have many components in the app and we have provided any specific names for the components as they take the class name by default but in case of obfuscation we are below exception

```
@Component
public class Configuration
```

We are having lots of component in our project.

Exception:

> 

```
ERROR - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto-configuration attributes found. Is com.Application annotated with EnableAutoConfiguration?
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:556)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.Application.main(Application.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto-configuration attributes found. Is com.Application annotated with EnableAutoConfiguration?
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAttributes(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:126)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:547)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone suggest better way than explicitly adding the names to each component?

---

**

> update

**

Main class file has following annotation as well

> @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={

even if we are using the simple demo project and try to obfuscate it

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Some how proguard is obfuscating the spring related files. I have explicitly keeping all the jars un obfuscated.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [com.example.demo.DemoApplication]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto-configuration attributes
>   found. Is com.example.demo.DemoApplication annotated with
>   EnableAutoConfiguration?

Updated . adding proguard.conf file

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
#-include ../build/annotations.pro


-keeppackagenames
-keepdirectories
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontwarn

#-applymapping input_mapping.dat
#-printmapping final_mapping.dat
#-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
#-forceprocessing
-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Deprecated,Signature,Exceptions,*Annotations*
#-ignorewarnings

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes that have a main method.

-keep class !com.companyname.** { *; }


-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.* *;
} 

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* *;
}
```

Comment: Add @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation to your primary configuration class

Comment: We are already using the@SpringBootApplication in the main class so we dont need to use the @EnableAutoConfiguration.

Comment: could you post your proguard conf ?

Comment: @JEY i have added the proguard conf file.

Comment: are you creating runnable jar ?

Comment: yes  we are creating

Comment: are you creating doing proguard task before the spring repackaging ?

Comment: nope. i have found the solution. This is not an optimize solution but it works. will paste the answer soon